# indenting a generated html div class with the help of css

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass

I am writing an app with `rails.` I am not very familiar with css yet. Though, i am trying. And have a question, my html tags generated are

```
<div class="sub-product post-1">
 // content goes here
</div>

<div class="sub-product post-2">
 // content goes here
</div>

<div class="sub-product post-3">
 // content goes here
</div>

<div class="sub-product post-4">
 // content goes here
</div>
```

Now, as you can see there different numbers arranged to `post`. What i was trying to do is show them indented and here is my css

```
.sub-product.post-1 {
margin:30px
}
```

It works but if I make it `.sub-product.post-1.post-2.post-3.post-4` it does show indented. I think i know whats wrong here, but what is an elegant solution to show them indented?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add these CSS rules:

```
.sub-product {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.post-1 {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.post-2 {
    margin-left: 60px;
}

.post-3 {
    margin-left: 90px;
}

.post-4 {
    margin-left: 120px;
}
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x35Fb/3/)

Comment: I want to apply different margins to different post types. Post-1 is 30px indented from the start. Post-2 30 more and so on until post-4.

Comment: yes it does help. is there some other way (more neater way to do it) ?

Comment: No =( you only can refer for an element with a specific style about this way (in this case).

Answer (score 1):

You could nest your `post-*` divs to make more clear that they have a parent-child relation (at least that's what I assume based on your post):

```
<div class="sub-product post-1">
// content goes here
    <div class="sub-product post-2">
    // content goes here
        <div class="sub-product post-3">
        // content goes here
           <div class="sub-product post-4">
               // content goes here
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way you will only need the following CSS:

```
.sub-product[class^=post-] { // class starts with post-
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done neatly through jQuery. Just add the following code to your HTML doc, and you can do it for simply any number of divs.

```
<script>

//iterate through all divs that have .sub-product class
$('.sub-product').each(function(){

    //save the class of each div in a variable
    var num = $(this).attr('class');

    //fetch just the number from each classname
    num = num.replace('sub-product post-', '');

    //change the margin-left of each div based on its class number
    $(this).css({
        marginLeft: num*30+'px'
    });
});
</script>
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/Tv347/11/

Otherwise, if you strictly want to use CSS, your best bet would be to apply styles to individual divs like this :

```
.post-1{
    margin-left:30px
}

.post-2{
    margin-left:60px
}

.post-3{
    margin-left:90px
}

.post-4{
    margin-left:120px
}
```

Comment: I want to apply different margins to different post types. Post-1 is 30px indented from the start. Post-2 30 more and so on until post-4.

Comment: I have provided a javascript solution that will universally take care of any number of your divs :)